# VBA - inserting a star based on a cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to insert star shapes into my spreadsheet into cells which contain a specific value (e.g. "Y").
I want this to be a macro assigned to a button.

Is anyone able to help - not even sure where to begin.
From my trawl through the internet, I can only work out how to add the shape randomly placed in the spreadsheet.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the star *(aShape)* to cover-up the underlying value in the cell ??

Comment: @Gary's Student - yes I would like it to sit over the cell that has the "Y" value in.

Comment: I know it isn't VBA, but if Y in your case is a numeric value then it could easily be done through conditional formatting. You'll need one condition to have the star icon show when value Y is true, then use a second condition to have textcolor change to white when value is Y. If Y is a text string then VBA is your way and answer below is good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a sample to get you started.  You must adapt it to meet your specific needs.  The code:

```
Sub KoverTheYs()
    Dim T As Long, L As Long, W As Long, H As Long
    Dim r As Range, shp As Shape
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If r.Value = "Y" Then
            L = r.Left
            T = r.Top
            W = r.Width
            H = r.Height
            Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(92, 100, 20, 60, 60)
            shp.Top = T
            shp.Left = L
            shp.Width = W
            shp.Height = H
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

**Note:**

- I am not addressing any of the Button stuff - you will have to code adding the button and linking it to the star-painter.
- I am not addressing the exact color and shape of the star